# Android Custom CursorAdapter - Get primary key in getView?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I've got some code in GetView in a custom CursorAdapter that requires the primary key, and would like to set a variable equal to it.

How do I do this efficiently? GetView takes in position, convertView, and a GridView parent as arguments, so I don't have the cursor there.

Comment: How about using `PagedListAdapter` instead of `CursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your adapter to translate ListView line number `position`.

I use code similar to [this](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorAdapter.java)

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    ...

    /** internal helper. return null if position is not available */
    private Cursor getCursorAt(int position) {
        return (Cursor) getItem(position);
    }

    /** translates offset in adapter to id of image */
    public long getImageId(int position) {
        Cursor cursor = getCursorAt(position);

        return cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MY_LONG_COLUMN_NAME));
    }

}
```

Comment: Would getItem(position) work even if, say, I deleted an object from the Database later?

Comment: if you are using a contentprovider as datasource of the cursoradapter your ListActivity can register that it wants to be informed of changes so it can reload the listview.